# Read file using redirected stdin C++

Tags: c++, parsing, stdin

Good day. I am having quite a problem with how to read a file line by line and put it into an array. We were asked to get the needed data from a text file using this command line argument.

```
program.exe < input.txt
```

and the input.txt goes like this:

```
4 4
*...
....
.*..
....
```

How am I going to parse this wherein the integers would be the value of the rows and columns respectively, and the "*" and "." should go into a 2d array? Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use two `int`s to store the number of rows and columns and an `std::vector` of `std::string` to store the characters.

Code:

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int row, col;
    cin>>row>>col;
    vector<string> m(row);
    for(int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
        cin>>m[i];
}
```

## Edit:

As you do not know when how many character tables you need to enter, here is the updated code.
Code:

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int row, col;
    //This is where your main data is stored.
    vector<vector<string> >m;
    //This will terminate if EOF is encountered.
    while (cin >> row)
    {
        cin>>col;
        //A temporary vector to enter your data.
        vector<string> temp(row);
        for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
        {
            cin>>temp[i];
        }
        m.push_back(temp);
    }
    //Do what you want with 'm'.
    //You can access the nth instance using m[n-1].
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but how about if there is more data like in the above? For example:

4 4
*...
....
.*..
....
2 2
..
.*

I tried looping it but it does not terminate.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Try this, and let me know if any problems occur.